# Updating a html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, caching, heroku

I'm hosting my little project on Heroku.

My problem is that when I write to an HTML file it's code, for example

```
fs.writeFile('home.html', <html><body>Hello</body><html>, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

It write to the file and everything is ok but it doesn't update it. So if I would enter the page after the update, I'll see the old one. I've tested it offline and it worked ok.

It's not taking the page from the cache. I've put

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

In the HTML file and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem):

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted. For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of normal dyno management.

You can write to it but any changes will be lost when your dyno restarts, which happens frequently.

Depending on your use case you should be using a [data store](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) (Heroku [provides a PostgreSQL database](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) by default, but there are other options) or [a third-party file storage service like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).