# Files not being created in php Heroku

Tags: php, html, heroku

I have some code which creates a file every time a user inputs some data via a form. I have tested the code on localhost, and the file gets created in the directory, however, after deploying it to Heroku the file does not get created.

Can someone please help me?

Here is the sample code :

```php
$fp = fopen(''.$topic.$name.$title.'.php', 'a+');
```

Comment: Please provide a portion of the code that would allow people to understand your code better. Currently there is not much info to work with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating a html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50330040/updating-a-html-file)

Comment: And why are you doing this in the first place? Are you trying to build a CMS? Writing files to the filesystem isn't a good approach here. Write one controller and load your `$topic` / `$name` / `$title` data from your database based on a query string.